# Granger Causality Equation between daily Carry Trade returns and daily Stock Market returns

Tags: fx, econometrics

Could someone please kindly help me in regards to a question on the Carry Trade.

What is the most widely used equation for the carry trade including the funding and investment currency and what equation is appropriate to state when analysing Granger Causality between daily carry trade returns and daily stock market returns including lags? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is "the Carry Trade".

Comment: @Attack68, it typically involves selling a low yielding currency and buying a higher yielding asset netting the difference in yield.